# How do I prevent closing of jQuery modal dialog when asp buttons inside dialog are clicked?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I am attempting to resolve an issue for a jQuery UI modal dialog that contains several asp controls which have server side events.  Each time an asp control inside the dialog is clicked, the modal dialog closes.  These asp controls do have server side logic that just execute to interact with the modal.

I have included the logic to append the dialog to the form (see below).  The appendTo works well for other dialogs in my solution that have controls that postback.

The only difference for this modal is that the Div is contained inside a user control.

Below is the script used to open the dialog:

```
var $splitdialog;

// render html using web service, then GetSplitViewComplete will open the modal dialog

openDistributedReferenceCodesSplitModalDialog = function (splitdialogDivId, EntityType, EntityId, AllowAdd, AllowAdhoc) {
    $splitdialog = $("#" + splitdialogDivId);
    $splitdialog.empty();
    WebServices.DistributedReferenceCodesService.GetSplitView(EntityType, EntityId, AllowAdd, AllowAdhoc, GetSplitViewComplete);
};

GetSplitViewComplete = function (result) {
    // neccessary to support postback for button, dropdowns, etc on modal
    $splitdialog.append(result.InnerHtml);
    $splitdialog.dialog({ width: 800 }, { height: 'auto' }, { modal: true });
    $splitdialog.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
};
```

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the difference with the dialogs that do work. What kind of controls are being used? ASP.NET Controls, Ajax Toolkit Controls, JQuery UI Controls?

Comment: The difference with this dialog is that the div that is used to open the dialog is in a user control.  The user control is repeated inside a listview.  I open the jQuery modal dialog by attaching a script to a button which includes the unique id for the div to open as a modal.  Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, can't help you from here. There is just not enough to work with. It's always hard to find these problems when your mixing ajax behavior with server controls which are not ajaxified. I don't say it can't be done but I try to avoid this as much a possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to use an UpdatePanel to prevent the modal popup from closing.  Try something like this...

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/why-does-modalpopup-close-on-postback

Comment: Thank you for the information, but this does not resolve this issue.  The div that is used to open the jQuery modal dialog exists in a user control.  The contents displayed in the modal dialog are another user control that is rendered via a webservice.  The asp controls that have server side events that must process before the modal closes are contained within an update panel.